# finding only positive factors

Tags: python-3.x, factors

user enters a positive integer, then prints a list of all positive integers that divide into said number evenly, excluding itself and 1, in ascending order.

I have tried two variations but can't seem to get anything other than 12, 12 times

```
num_1 = int(input("please enter an integer:"))
print("the factors of", num_1, "are")
for value in range(2,num_1):
    if num_1 % 2 ==0:
        print (num_1)
    elif num_1 ==num_1
        break
```

i expect

```
2
3
4
6
```

also, I am not supposed to use the "break"

Comment: `elif num_1 == num_1` is _always_ true. Did you mean to use `value` inside the loop? For example: `if num_1 % value == 0: print (value)`

Comment: What number are you giving as input to the program?

Comment: `break` doesn't make sense in your code. The `for value in range ...` stops automatically when the range is completed. Note that range (2,6) goes 2,3,4,5 thus stopping just before the 6.

Answer (score 0):

I dint quite understand what you want but this may be the solution you are looking for.

```
num_1 = int(input("please enter an integer: "))
print("The factors of ", num_1, " are: ")

for value in range(2, num_1):
    if num_1 % value == 0:
        print(value)
```

Comment: what does he mean by `should divide the no evenly`.